# How to change textview padding inside listview?

Tags: android, listview, textview, padding

This is activity_main.xml. I could not change padding by adding paddingTop, paddingBottom. What should I do to change padding.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_word_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/et_word_search"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_word_search" >

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is selected_word.xml which includes 3 textviews. These textview appear in listview.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_selected_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="Selected name"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_selected_desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_selected_cost"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:text="Selected description"
        android:background="@drawable/back"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_selected_cost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Selected Cost"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: screenshot is here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/93574523/SC20130608-183830.png

Comment: Use gravity attribute in your layout.. then your spacing will be perfect..

Comment: tried to use gravity top nothing happened

Comment: I am sorry to have said the wrong termm.. use "weight"

Comment: no idea how to use weight here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"`android:layout_padding` or `android:layout_paddingLeft` or `android:layout_paddingRight`" and so on ?

Comment: I want to change top and bottom paddings.I used android:layout_paddingTop android:layout_paddingBottom and nothing changed.

Comment: Did you mean android:padding..?